# Doxygen include graph

Tags: c++, c, header, include, doxygen

I know there is a doxygen option, to show include graphs, like
`a.cpp` includes `a.h` and `b.h`
`a.h` includes `c.h`
`c.h` includes `<unistd.h>`

But `unistd.h` does also include `<features.h>` for example!
How can I add the includes from 'system' headers, like `unistd.h` or `windows.h`, into the include dependency graph from doxygen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Though you can add the system header path to the `INPUT` variable as pmr suggests, I would make a case for *not* adding them to the include graph.

If you want to do this so that you can say "ah, `unistd.h` already includes `features.h` so I don't need to include it myself" then I would advise against it.  It's an implementation detail: you shouldn't care about it because it may change in a future version. If you need something in (eg) `features.h` then you should always include it because you can't rely on it already being included by a different header.

Answer (score 1):

This is hard because this would potentially document code that is included in those headers in your own documentation.

Usually doxygen will stop preprocessing when it cannot find a header in the directories specified in `INPUT`. You can add your system include directory to `INPUT` and hope for the best.

In general I prefer include documentation to end at library boundaries.